# Justifying $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot 2^k=2^{n+1}(n-1)+2$ using difference and shift operators

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot 2^k = 2^{n+1}(n-1)+2$$

How can I justify that using difference and shift operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write$$k\cdot 2^k=(k-1)\cdot 2^{k+1}-(k-2)\cdot 2^k$$